# Error al generar .exe desde .jar Class Driver - MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ant, launch4j

He desarrollado una aplicación **agenda** en **Netbeans** la cual funciona correctamente dentro de **Netbeans**.

Mi problema viene cuando quiero ejecutar la aplicación fuera de **Netbeans** (MySQL failed), después de generar el `.exe` a partir del `.jar` (`Clean and build`).  al generar el exe no te está metiendo el driver de mysql

Al generar el `.exe`, intuyo que no está metiendo el **driver** de **MySQL** en el archivo.

¿Cómo hago la conexión a la base de datos para loguearme en la app?

**Código:**

```
public class Conexiones {
    static String bbdd = "agenda";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static Connection c = null;

    /**
     * Conexión a BBDD.
     *
     * @param bbdd
     * @return
     */
    public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
            return c;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //Siempre entra aquí cuando ejecuto desde el .exe !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed! Se cerrará el programa...", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed! Se cerrará el programa...", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Estructura de mi aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Repito: el fallo viene al ejecutar la APP fuera del Netbeans.

Genero el `.jar` y luego con el **Launch4j** genero el `.exe`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También, añado en la opción JRE que el mínimo sea 1.8.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, por último, ahora quiero ejecutar la aplicación y loguearme y a la hora de loguear me da el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿A qué se debe?**

Comment: "MySQL failed" da ***MUY POCA*** información... Cuando debugueas, no muestres mensajes sin sentido, muestra ***TRAZAS*** del error. Una de dos, o utilizas un *logger* para generar un log en txt que puedas leer (y pasarnos), o imprime en la pantalla la traza de la excepción, una vez lo tengas edita la pregunta y añádela.

Comment: @Benito-B Valoro tu explicación pero no la entendí, mi nivel de programación tampoco es superlativo. ¿Me dices que tengo que poner más excepciones para saber dónde exactamente está el error? ¿O cómo podría resolverlo?

Comment: @Benito-B Pregunta editada con código de comprobación al final de la pregunta.

Comment: No no, no necesitas poner más excepciones, necesitas poder ***ver*** las excepciones! Las excepciones no son malas per se, en su mensaje te indican la causa del problema! Por eso cuando haces un `try...catch`, en el `catch` jamás debes *esconder* la excepción! Toda excepción lleva asociado un `stack trace` que debes poder ver cuando ocurre una excepción. Eso es lo que debes mostrar, el stack trace de las excepciones

Comment: @Benito-B Es que no entiendo nada. No sé porque el mismo programa funciona dentro de Netbeans y fuera de Netbeans (en el ejecutable .exe) da el fallo al loguearse.

Comment: En tus `catch` pones `e.printStackTrace();`, pero si no estás ejecutando la aplicación en netbeans, dónde puedes ver eso?? Por eso necesitas o usar un logger, o *imprimirla en la ventana*. Si no sabes por qué da fallo ***imprime los mensajes de las excepciones para poder verlo!!***

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121295/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-benito-b).

Comment: Después de una serie de comprobaciones, creo que el fallo está en que el .exe no coge correctamente la clase Driver MySQL

Comment: yo primero lo migraria de [tag:ant] a [tag:maven] para asegurarme que lleva todas las dependencias necesarias